# Anychart Standalone Legend Load From JSON

Tags: json, legend, anychart, fromjson

We create our chart with Json using the anychart.fromJson method.
So we have methods to build the Json and that's also the way we make our chart legends.
Now in certain situations we need these legends as standalone legends. For example when we need two or more legends in a chart.

Is it possible to create standalone legends from Json?
Otherwise we have to duplicate our code completely and create them all again using the anychart functions, which would be very cumbersome.

Many greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library 8.7.1 doesn't support creating standalone instances from JSON configuration. It can be created only using the JS API.

Comment: That's a pity.
I hope one day it is possible.